# How to print diamond shape pattern in C?

Tags: c

---

how to print diamond shape pattern like this?
the pattern isn't commonly using "*" only but it't modified with "."

The input:
5

The output:

```
....0.....
...000....
..0.0.0...
.0..0..0..
000000000.
.0..0..0..
..0.0.0...
...000....
....0.....
```

Here my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    int number, i, k, count = 1;
 
    scanf("%d", &number);
    count = number - 1;
    for (k = 1; k <= number; k++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            printf(".");
        count--;
        for (i = 1; i <= 2 * k - 1; i++)
            printf("0");
        printf("\n");
     }
     count = 1;
     for (k = 1; k <= number - 1; k++)
     {
         for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
             printf(".");
         count++;
         for (i = 1 ; i <= 2 *(number - k)-  1; i++)
             printf("0");
         printf("\n");
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post text, not screenshots of text.

Comment: If you put your title in just about any search engine you should be getting plenty of links to others with similar problems. Many of whom have solutions, and some that even have explanations about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I rapidly wrote this for fun keeping your approach, however this is not the most efficient nor the most elegant way of doing this

```
int number, i, k, count = 1;

scanf("%d", &number);
for (k = 0; k < number-1; k++){
    i = 1;
    while(i < number-k){
        printf(".");
        i++;
    }
    printf("0");
    i++;
    while(i< number){
        printf(".");
        i++;
    }
    if(i==number){
        printf("0");
        i++;
    }
    while(i<number+k){
        printf(".");
        i++;
    }
    if(k>0){
        printf("0");
        i++;
    }
    while(i<number*2){
        printf(".");
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

You will probably find better answers if you [search a bit deeper](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-print-hollow-pyramid-diamond-pattern/)

---

Also, you can just

```
void printpir(int number, int k){
         int i = 1;
        while(i < number-k){
            printf(".");
            i++;
        }
        printf("0");
        i++;
        while(i< number){
            printf(".");
            i++;
        }
        if(i==number){
            printf("0");
            i++;
        }
        while(i<number+k){
            printf(".");
            i++;
        }
        if(k>0){
            printf("0");
            i++;
        }
        while(i<number*2){
            printf(".");
            i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int number, i, k, count = 1;
 
    scanf("%d", &number);
    for (k = 0; k < number-1; k++){
        printpir(number, k);
    }

    for(i= 1; i<number*2; i++){
        printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
    k--;
    for (; k >= 0; k--)
     {
         printpir(number, k);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of a Cartesian coordinate system whose origin is the center of symmetry of the diamond pattern to be drawn. The `0`s reside in the lines `y = x + (n - 1)`, `y = -x + (n - 1)`, `y = x - (n - 1)`, `y = -x - (n - 1)`, and the axes `y = 0`, `x = 0`. Then we can easily codify this information to draw the diamond pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_diamond (int n)
{
    --n;
    for (int y = n; y >= -n; --y) {
        for (int x = -n; x <= n; ++x)
            putchar(x == 0 || y == 0
                    || y == x + n || y == -x + n || y == x - n || y == -x - n
                    ? '0' : '.');
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    print_diamond(5);
}
```

The line

```
|| y == x + n || y == -x + n || y == x - n || y == -x - n
```

can be reduced to

```
|| abs(x - y) == n || abs(x + y) == n
```

after `stdlib.h` is `#include`d.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with only 2 `for-loop`s. I can explain my answer if you need it. 
Hope you can understand...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, _i, i, _j, j, k;
 
    printf("Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (_i = 1; _i < 2*n; _i++) {
        i = abs(_i - n);
        for (_j = 1; _j <= 2*n; _j++) {
            j = abs(_j - n);
            if (j < n-i) {
                if (i==0 || j == 0 || (i+j==n-1)) {
                    printf("0");
                } else {
                    printf(".");
                }
            } else {
                printf(".");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```